# Back button not showing after adding fragment manually

Tags: android, android-fragments

After adding new fragment manually the back button not showing on the toolbar. 
If I am using the XML fragment action works even when put my fragment in the XML.

```
  FragmentTransaction ft 
  =businessOwnersFragment.fragManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new 
    ServicesFragment(businessOwnerModel));
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
```

After adding this code no back button shown.

but if I add my fragment as action:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.mawaeed.businessowner.BusinessOwnersFragment"
    android:label="@string/home_title"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_busnissowner" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_serviceFragment"
        app:destination="@id/serviceFragment" />
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/serviceFragment"
    android:name="com.mawaeed.businessowner.services.ServicesFragment"
    android:label="@string/nav_example1"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_services" />
```

The back button shows.

```
public void setUpToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (supportActionBar != null) {
        supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I know I can add:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = myContext.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

 Toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_18dp)
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

But I want to make this automatic.

I want to show the Back button when adding my fragment without adding extra code

Comment: Why are you manually adding a Fragment if you're using Navigation?

Comment: Showing a back button is not automatic.  Its not built into the OS, as the normal method is to use the system back button.  Back buttons tend to be from ported iOS apps where they didn't bother to make it Android like.  If you want one, you have to enable it manually.  Although you can write helper functions that make it easier.